# Use current page data in the next page

Tags: jquery, css, html, cordova

I am developing a application where I need to use current page content in the next page. The content is dynamic so I need a way to handle this. I am developing the application using phonegap and jQuery. If the stored values in `a.html` is:

```
var numberArray = [ "11","12","13","22","07","45" ];
```

How should I be able to get those values in `b.html`?

Comment: To store it server-side use a database, the session or a cookie depending on the persistence required. To store it locally use localStorage.

Comment: I would recommend using PHP for something like this.

Comment: Have a look at this : http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html I have used it before and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP includes.

Have an index page that runs your backend code. Make it include page a, then when you click the button to take you to page b include page b.

Comment: Thanks mate, but I need to use only HTML5.. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need only html5?

Answer (score 0):

If your are not opening new window/tab, you can persist data in window.

e.g. `window.var1="some data"`

Then you can access data by using window.var1

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage supported by HTML5 to pass values to next page.
If you want to save an array, we can stringify it first before saving.

To Save into local storage:

```
var numberArray = [ "11","12","13","22","07","45" ];
localStorage["numberArray"] = JSON.stringify(numberArray);
```

To read from local storage:

```
var storedNumberArray = JSON.parse(localStorage["numberArray"]);
```

Code sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/KGCXR/